# Concatenate/Merge/Join two different Dataframes Pandas

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am looking to join two dataframes using pandas on the 'Date' columns. I usually use df2= pd.concat([df, df1],axis=1), however for some reason this is not working.

In this example, i am pulling the data from a sql file, creating a new column called 'Date' that is merging my year and month columns, and then pivoting. Whne i try and concatenate the two dataframes, the dataframe shows up side by side instead of merged together.

What comes up:
Date   Count of Cats    Date    Count of Dogs

What I want to come up:

Date   Count of Cats    Count of Dogs

Any ideas?
My other problem is I am trying to make sure the Date columns writes to excel as a string and not a datetime function. Please keep this is mind when thinking about a solution.

Here is my code:

```
executeScriptsFromFile('cats.sql')
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
df.columns = [rec[0] for rec in cursor.description]
monthend = {'Q1':'3/31','Q2':'6/30','Q3':'9/30','Q4':'12/31'}
df['Date']=df['QUARTER'].map(monthend)+'/'+ df['YEAR']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df10= df.pivot_table(['Breed'], ['Date'], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
df10.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df10.reindex_axis(['Breed', 'Count of Cats'], axis=1)
df10.columns = ('Breed', 'Count of Cats')


executeScriptsFromFile('dogs.sql')
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
df.columns = [rec[0] for rec in cursor.description]
monthend = {'Q1':'3/31','Q2':'6/30','Q3':'9/30','Q4':'12/31'}
df['Date']=df['QUARTER'].map(monthend)+'/'+ df['YEAR']
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df11= df.pivot_table(['Breed'], ['Date'], aggfunc=np.sum,fill_value=0)
df11.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df11.reindex_axis(['Breed', 'Count of Dogs'], axis=1)
df11.columns = ('Breed', 'Count of Dogs')
df11a= df11.round(0)

df12= pd.concat([df10, df11a],axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you add some samples of your dataframes? Also is some difference of type of `df10.index` and `d11.index` ? Because this should work.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seem you need remove `df10.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)` and `df11.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)`, please test it.

Comment: Or maybe need remove only one level, need `date` as index in both dataframes before `concat`

Comment: so what i did was took out df10.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df10.reindex_axis(['Breed', 'Count of Cats'], axis=1)
df10.columns = ('Breed', 'Count of Cats')
& df11.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df11.reindex_axis(['Breed', 'Count of Dogs'], axis=1)
df11.columns = ('Breed', 'Count of Dogs') and was able to concat from there. However I need my Date column to be a string so it looks better where I write to excel. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Yes, you can convert it to string like `df.index = df.index.astype(str)`

Comment: I know this sounds stupid but do you know how long I have been trying to do that? All sorts of work around, ugh. Thank you so much @ jezrael

Comment: Good luck, and i think is I think it is not stupid, sometimes man works with easy think 2-3 hour and cannot find problem. So good luck and i am not sure if create answer. what do you think?

Comment: yes- this is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to remove code:

```
df10.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
df11.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

because need level `date` in `index` for [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) by `date`.

Also for convert index to `string` use:

```
df.inde = df.index.astype(str)
```